# Как пропустить/перейти в конец строки при считывании файла C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Есть файл с текстом. Программа считывает всё посимвольно. Если находит, к примеру букву из английского алфавита - нужно перейти на следующую строку для считывания.  как это реализовать?
Вот отрывок кода:

```
string s;
char sy;
while (file.get(sy)) // считываем файл посимвольно
{  
    s = s + sy;
    if (sy == '.') {
        textStr.push_back(s);
        CheckCorrectInput(str); //функция ищет англ символы.
        if (eror) { // если функция нашла то...
            ПЕРЕЙТИ НА СЛЕДУЮЩУЮ СТРОКУ
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while(sy!='\n')file.get(sy); а вообще лучше сразу весь файл считать.

Comment: Не совсем то, что я имел в виду. Если эта буква будет посередине слова, то вашим способом мы её считаем, если я правильно понял.

Comment: @Jap_Story ```\n``` - символ переноса строки, собственно вы считываете символы вникуда (т.е. переставляете указатель в файле) пока его не встретите. Еще можете обратить внимание на [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477408/ifstream-end-of-line-and-move-to-next-line)

Answer (score 2):

getline(filename,s) - то что вам нужно?

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Выдернул часть своего кода.

```
void MyString::CheckCorrectInput(string textStr){
    try {
        error = true;
        if (textStr.check_symb()) throw "Недопустимые символы\nПовторите попытку\n";
            error = false;
    }
    catch (const char* v) {
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Незапланированная исключительная ситуация";
    }
    
}

void MyString::InputFromFile() {
        while (getline(file, s1)) { // считываем строку из файла
            error = false;  //Флажок для пропуска строки. Значение меняется в функции CheckCorrectInput
            for (char sy : s1) { //Проверяем каждый элемент в строке
                if (sy == '\n') continue; //если переход на след. строку ничего не делать
                s = s + sy; // добавить в строку символ             
                if (sy == '.') { // Если символ точка, то закинуть это предложение в вектор типа string. Можно и без этого, но это маленькая часть моего кода, поэтому мне это нужно.
                    textStr.push_back(s);

                    for (string str : textStr) {
                        if (error) { break; }// проверяем флаг, который ищется в CheckCorrectInput. По умолчанию значение false
                        cout << "\nПредложение №" << i << " ";
                        CheckCorrectInput(str); // поиск буквы из англ. языка
                        i++; 
                    }
                    textStr.pop_back();// убрать элемент из вектора
                    s.clear();//очистить строку
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Мда... После getline ожидать перевода строки... Проверка ошибок это вообще нечто. Это вообще не должно работать.